# What is an outer measure?

Tags: measure-theory

I know the definition of an outer measure. Let X be a set. An outer measure on X is a function $\theta : \mathcal{P}X \to [0,\infty]$ such that

(i) $\theta(\emptyset)=0$

(ii) if $ A \subseteq B \subseteq X$ then $\theta(A) \leq \theta(B)$

(iii) for every sequence $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of subsets of X, $\theta( \cup _{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n) \leq \sum^\infty _{n=1} \theta(A_n)$

What is the purpose of the outer measure?  When do we need to use the outer measure and why?

Does $\mathcal{P}$ mean the power set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\mathcal{P}$ means the powerset of the set.

As for the purpose, it's a way to approximate a proper measure on a set.

You can think of it in old terms on an euclidean plane where outer measures are rectangles, you try to find find the correct measure of any shape by successively getting smaller and smaller rectangles and infinitely many such that we can get a measure for a circle or any other 2 dimensional shape.

Comment: Great analogy. How did you "see" that analogy from the definition? Why do we need the power set in this definition rather than an arbitrary set?

Comment: The powerset is the set of ALL subsets which means it includes all possible subsets and hence is the most general. One however SHOULD note that such a function, due to paradoxes, can be extremely troublesome so it is usually just said from powerset, with some limitations on how these sets must be constructed and as such doesn't encompasses the entire powerset.

Comment: As for how to see it, think of rectangles as they are easy, what is the area of a none existent rectangle? 0 (the empty rectangle), the area of a bigger rectangle that contains a smaller rectangle must be greater than the smaller rectangle and the area of disjoint, aka non-overlapping rectangles must be the sum of the area of each individual rectangle.

Comment: Oh I see. Excellent !!

Comment: I should also add that if rectangles do overlap then clearly the sum of the area must be greater than the unioned area because some area pieces are being counted more than once. It is a fairly easy thing to visualize. Glad you liked it :)

Comment: What do you mean by "proper measure".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32948/discussion-between-zelos-malum-and-al-jabra).